# Postgres Query to aggregate and also individually list data

Tags: postgresql

So this is going to be a bit of an odd question but I am absolutely stuck on how to do this and it's blocking me from being able to finish a task I am working on.

I have the following DB structure (I know, its not pretty):

```
users

|   id   | company  |
| -------| -------- |
| user1  | company1 |
| user2  | company2 |

------

users_companies

| user_id| company  |
| -------| -------- |
| user1  | company3 |
| user1  | company4 |
| user2  | company5 |
| user2  | company6 |
```

I need to write a query that will return the following result set

```
| user1  | company1 |
| user1  | company3 |
| user1  | company4 |
| user1  | company1,company3,company4 |
| user2  | company2 |
| user2  | company5 |
| user2  | company6 |
| user2  | company2,company5,company6 |
```

As you can see for each user it will individually list out each company and also create an aggregate row of all their companies they are assigned to. I am completely lost on how to get this result set and any help in the right direction would be super helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by approaching it as two separate queries which you can union using a separate union of the data provided by a CTE; each query is a derived table with a defined *seq*uence which you can use for ordering:

```
with u as (
  select * 
  from users
  union all
  select * 
  from users_companies
)
select id, company
from (
  select id, Company, 1 seq
  from u
  union all
  select id, string_agg(company, ','), 2 seq
  from u
  group by Id, seq
)t
order by Id, seq, company;
```

See a [Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZEzr3czn)

Comment: Just a quick follow up: if i also wanted to sneak the users `email` in there is that possible. The users email only exists on the `users` table, not the `users_companies` table.

Comment: The `UNION ALL` in the CTE should be `UNION` unless there is a guarantee that no user/company pair can occur in both tables. I would also suggest ordering by company name in the aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an alternative using `GROUPING SETS`:

```
WITH uc AS (
    SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.company
      FROM users
    UNION
    SELECT user_companies.user_id, user_companies.company
      FROM user_companies
)
SELECT uc.user_id,
       STRING_AGG(uc.company, ', ' ORDER BY uc.company) AS company
  FROM uc
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (uc.user_id, (uc.user_id, uc.company))
 ORDER BY uc.user_id;
```

Please note that `UNION` is used instead of `UNION ALL` to protect against duplicate rows caused by user/company pairs occurring in both tables.

Answer (score -2):

I think you'll be able to get this with a little hint:

Make a query that gives you the aggregated data and then UNION ALL it with the query that gives you the non-aggregated data.